# Accessing an object containing data in List item

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program that uses a *dll toolkit to analyze trading auctions (like ebay) in a PC game.

The toolkit has a class "AuctionResponse" with a following field:

```
public List<AuctionInfo> AuctionInfo { get; set; }
```

In order to access the list I call the following method:

```
AuctionResponse.AuctionInfo
```

And then I convert the list data into Data table.

```
datagrid1.DataSource = AuctionResponse.AuctionInfo;
```

However, one of the items in the list is an object itself, and I cannot figure out how to access it directly.

For example, how can I access AuctionInfo ItemData info for further analysis? The toolkit was added as a reference, and I cannot edit its source code.

```
public class AuctionInfo

{
    public ItemData ItemData { get; set; }

    public string BidState { get; set; }

    public uint BuyNowPrice { get; set; }

    public uint CurrentBid { get; set; }

    public int Expires { get; set; }

}


public class ItemData

{
    public long AssetId { get; set; }

    public ushort Assists { get; set; }

    public List<Attribute> AttributeList { get; set; }

    public ushort CardSubTypeId { get; set; }

}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var tradePileResponse = await _client.GetTradePileAsync();
        rb1.Text = string.Format("Found {0} tradepile items", 
                   tradePileResponse.AuctionInfo.Count);

        datagrid1.DataSource = tradePileResponse.AuctionInfo.ItemData;
```

When I add .ItemData I get an error:

Error   CS1061  'List' does not contain a definition for 'ItemData' and no extension method 'ItemData' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: How are you trying to access it? What UI technology are you using? ASP.NET/WPF/WinForms? Because accessing the property is easy, `AuctionResponse.AuctionInfo.ItemData.AssetId` for example.

Comment: I'm using WinForms, thank you very much, I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: Your `tradePileResponse.AuctionInfo` is actually a `List` of `AuctionInfo`s.  You'll have to decide which one you want to access the ItemData from.

Comment: Is there a way to see what lists it contains, and then show the contents to a console-like textbox (as in Console.WriteLine()) in a console app)? I tried GetRange method, but it's not working, since as you said, it`s not applicable to a collection of lists.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much @SamPearson, you were absolutely right.

I tried to access ItemData through the following and it correctly accessed it.    
  
  
     `tradePileResponse.AuctionInfo[0].ItemData.Id.ToString();

      tradePileResponse.AuctionInfo[1].ItemData.ResourceId.ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve my problem by iterating through lists with foreach loop. For some reason, some elements became accessible inside the loop. Thank you very much @Sam Pearson and @Mike McCaughan for your suggestions.

```
        var tResponse = await _client.GetAsync();
        foreach (var response in tResponse.ListInfo)

        dataGridtest.Rows.Add(     response.ItemData.ResourceId,
                                   response.Item,
                                   response.Date,
                                   response.Expiration,
                                   response.Status

                                   );
```